# How can I run Ethereum node to profit from transaction fees and not from minning?

Tags: transactions, nodes, hardware

I understand that I need pretty good hardware for minning. But do I need the same hardware for running the Ethereum node just to confirm the transation and profit from Transaction fees?

I have a virtual machine as virtual sever running 24/h in datacenter and there are some CPU resources iddle, I pay the same price if the machine is use 1% or 99% percent of the resources I paid.

What are the recommended HW requirment to run this node for confirming transaction and not minning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BadrBellaj said currently only the miner will get a reward for mining a block. There is no separate reward for executing a smart contract.

But you can run a pool service and charge a fee to the miners. You must have a pretty good connections and be able to quickly handle lots of connections, to other Ethereum nodes and your miners. For example [Open Ethereum Mining pool](https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool) is a pool for Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

to validate the transactions and get the fees you need to be a miner, therfore you need to dispose of hardware with sufficiant hash power.